# Most efficient way to insert numbered columns into formatted text using standard Vim commands?

Tags: original-vim

I sometimes need to insert auto_incremented, numbered columns on other people's machines so I'm looking for a good way to do so without relying on any custom plugins, macros, or scripts; standard Vim commands only.

Example going from :

```
line a
line b
line c
...
line x
line y
line z
```

becoming then :

```
line a
line b
line 3 c
...
line 24 x
line 25 y
line z
```

doing something like

```
:3,25 something
```

If older versions of vim or vi have different ways of doing it I'd appreciate hearing about those solutions, too .

Comment: I would make user of `seq` unix program and virtual block mode.

Comment: Why not ... I also know how to use it as qa ; Y then p  + ctrl-A *number times ... but I am looking for more logical way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d actually do this using either [filbranden’s answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23038/343) or possibly a macro recording, but as you specifically requested an ex command that takes a `3,25` range, how about using a substitute command that uses as its replacement an expression that calls the `line()` function:

```
:3,25s/line \zs/\=line('.') . ' '
```

Or alternatively, a normal command using the same function:

```
:3,25norm!ea ^R=line('.')^M
```

Note that in the above, ^R is a literal CTRL-R character, and ^M is a CTRL-M. To insert them into the command line you need to type <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, respectively.

As [D. Ben Knoble points out in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23033/most-efficient-way-to-insert-numbered-columns-into-formatted-text-using-standard/23059?noredirect=1#comment41846_23059), you can avoid one of these special characters by "putting" the contents of the expression register, instead of inserting it:

```
:3,25norm! e"=line('.')^Mpi 
                           ^ note the space at the end of the line
```

#### Further details

**First command:**

- `:help /\zs`
- `:help sub-replace-expression`
- `:help line()`

**Second command:**

- `:help :normal`
- `:help i_CTRL-R`
- `:help quote_"`

Comment: Slightly less special characters: `:norm! "=line('.')^MP`. I was annoyed that `:%put =line('.')` didn't work, since `:put`'s range is used to determine the line to put on (i.e., it only works on one line at a time)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Nice spot!

Answer (score 3):

I'd solve this using blockwise Visual mode and the <kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Visual mode command, that increments each line in the selection by a successive number, effectively creating an incrementing sequence. (See [`:help v_g_CTRL-A`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#v_g_CTRL-A).)

This is the way I'd do it (especially if I was playing [Vimgolf](https://www.vimgolf.com/)):

1. `/c<CR>` to put the cursor on the `c` character at the start of the block.
2. `<C-V>` to begin [blockwise Visual mode](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#blockwise-visual).
3. `/y<CR>` to move to the `y` character that ends the selection.
4. `I2 <Esc>` to insert a `2` and a space on that column. Note that in blockwise Visual mode, this will insert the contents on *every* line of the selection. We're using `2` here instead of `3` because then we can increment *every* line of the selection and we don't need to shrink it on the second step.
5. `gv` to restore the selection once again. This will keep the column of `2`s selected.
6. `g<C-A>` to increment them all.

Ta-da!

If you had inserted `3` instead of `2`, you can still use this method, by skipping the increment on the first line. After `gv` you can use `o` to jump to the other end of the selection and then `j` to shrink the selection, removing the first line from it. After that, `g<C-A>` will increment from second to last line, achieving the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

While I was experimenting with [Rich's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23059/10604), I came up with

```
:global/./put =line('.')|join
```

Which can be shortened to `:g/./pu =line('.')|j`.

And yes, you can adjust the range of `:global`—`:3,25g/./pu =line('.')|j` will work.

Note: this puts the line number at the *beginning* of the line, at which point you might as well work with `:3,25s/^/\=line('.')`. Since you need the number in the middle, you could do something like

```
:3,25global/./put =line('.')|join|normal! 0dawwp
```

But at this point, again, you might as well use something else.